# Specifying a list fields for searching result in django-haystack

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I just wondering is there a way to specify returned fields for search request to the backend elasticsearch. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html for how to specify list in JSON API.

Let me explain why i need this. I have lots of articles with a large text data. Searching in this case is very slow, cause elasticsearch returns a whole large texts for each search results, but i want to render only titles except a whole text.

May be is there another way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple options here

1. You can use the fields option in Elasticsearch to specify the list of fields value that has to be returned. This will save some latency time as only less data has to be transported back. But then actual data would be stored as _source and it has to be fetched from hard disk and deserialized for each call.
   LINK - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html
2. In case we don't want to retrieve this field but you just want that field to be searchable. You can disable _source and enable store for each field whose data needs to be retrievable. 
   LINK , _source - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html
   LINK , store - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html

Djanko haystack documentation - http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchresult_api.html#SearchResult.get_additional_fields

Comment: Both options are good for me, but there are no options in `django-haystack` for handle it :(

Comment: I have added the djanko haystack documentation link in the asnwer. :)

Comment: I think `get_additional_fields` does something else.